# MacOS Keychain: Why not all user's keychains are being listed when remotely running the command `security list-keychains`

Tags: macos, security, keychain, fastlane, codesign

By running `security list-keychain -d user` locally, all user's keychains are listed, as expected... However, when remotely (ssh) running the same command, only the `system keychain` is presented.

Even weirder, when locally running the `security default-keychain -d user` command, it correctly presents the `login keychain` but when running the same command remotely (ssh) it keeps presenting the `system keychain`.

BTW, I'm running both commands with the same user.

Things that I've already tried to solve this:

1. Unlock all the keychains
2. Allow any application to access keychains certificates' private keys.
   2.1 Allow `ssh` and `ssh-agent` apps to access those private keys as well
3. Tried to add those keychains to the search list
4. And other things I can't even remember

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By restarting the mac mini machine, the problem was solved. Once again `reboot` to the rescue...
Hope this can help anyone out there.

Have fun.